# how to pass an object to a directive template in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to make a re-usable directive with ui-bootstrap modal.

It's almost working except the options

here is the directive :

```
directive('update', function() {
return {
  restrict: "E", 
  templateUrl: "tplModal.html",
  scope: { 
    selected:"="
  },
  link: function(scope, elm, attr){
    scope.open = function (obj) {
      scope.shouldBeOpen = true;
    };

    scope.close = function () {
      scope.shouldBeOpen = false;
    };

    scope.opts = {
      backdropFade: true,
      dialogFade:true
    };
  }
}
```

})

and tplModal.html

```
<button class='btn' ng-click='open(selected)'>Update</button>
    <div modal="shouldBeOpen" close="close()" options="opts">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3><i class="lead" icon="{{selected.type}}"></i> {{selected.name}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <!-- stuffs here -->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-warning cancel" ng-click="close()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

despite the `scope.opts`, there is no fade effect.

here is the whole code : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ab4BOH?p=preview

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Post the code here, tell how you use the directive, tell what you expect the code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: Your plunk doesn't work, I got "Plunk not found" error.

Comment: Post the code of tplModal.html

Comment: sorry. I updated the question and the link to the plnkr is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you add `opts` property to scope in the **post-linking function**, which will be called **after** modal directive's linking function, so the modal directive will never get those options.

The solution is to move `scope.opts = ...` to **pre-linking function**:

```
directive('update', function() {
    return {
        ...
        compile: function() {
            return {
                pre: function(scope, elm, attr){
                    ...
                    scope.opts = {
                        backdropFade: true,
                        dialogFade: true
                    };
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/iZaEiM?p=preview

Comment: thanks a lot ! i have been turning this upside down for the last couple of hours, and i was still far from the answer. Now, if i use another component inside the modal (e.g. ui-bootstrap datepicker or ngUpload), should i put the related functions inside this pre-linking function ?

Comment: @desgnl You could but you don't have to put functions in pre-linking function, it really depends on when your functions will be called. If the function will be called later in time, such as event handlers, it's safe to define them in the post-linking function.